# IPIP virtual interface experiencing discards

Tags: linux, linux-networking

I've established route-based IPSec connection via IPIP tunnel to Amazon (using StrongSwan), and on tunnel statistics I see incrementing discards. On physical interface there was some discards too, but I increased the ring buffer (ethtool -G). So now physical interface is OK.

I can't imagine where could be a problem. Because IPSec tunnel is Up. But increasing discards on that particular interface getting me nervous..

```
VTI_awssg1: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1422
    inet 169.254.134.26  netmask 255.255.255.252  destination 169.254.134.25
    inet6 fe80::200:5efe:b954:3ce9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    tunnel   txqueuelen 1000  (IPIP Tunnel)
    RX packets 164515900  bytes 18901337790 (17.6 GiB)
    **RX errors 206912  dropped 206912**  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 110799736  bytes 85951146842 (80.0 GiB)
    TX errors 6  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 6  collisions 0
```

OS: Centos 7.9

Any help ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a very interesting question.

I've looked into the source code.

Seems like there is only [single line](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/xfrm/xfrm_input.c#L751) related with incrementing of these counters.

Unfortunately you should use the kernel with enabled `CONFIG_XFRM_STATISTICS` option to see the exact reasons of these errors.

The brief description of errors read in [the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/xfrm_proc.html). More detailed meaning of these metrics you can see in the source code of [xfrm_input](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/xfrm/xfrm_input.c#L459) functiion.

Comment: thanks, now i see the same number of errors in ip -s tunnel show. I just need to understand what does it mean, and if it has effect on real traffic,..

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with replay window setting. Default Strongswan value of 32 was too small. Increased it to 1024 - errors disappeared.